# Why gradlew bootRun failed with `command 'java'`?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a project with successful building but failed to start, so I ran it with `--debug` asking for more detail

```
$ ./gradlew bootRun --debug
...
20:40:40.568 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
20:40:40.568 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command 'D:\prefix\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe'.
20:40:40.569 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
20:40:40.569 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'D:\prefix\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe'' finished with exit value -1 (state: FAILED)
...
```

It looks like `command 'java'` things got problem, so I manually run command

```
$ command 'D:\prefix\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe'
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.
```

This one looks fine, I'm not sure what's the problem now... thanks in advance

Comment: Did you define the main class? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-main-class? Do you have a main class?

Comment: @JBNizet let me check, see you later